# How to use RxSwift with NVActivityIndicatorView?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, uiactivityindicatorview, indicator

I'm trying to use `NVActivityIndicatorView` with `RxSwift` and `MVVM`.
I'm extending `NVActivityIndicatorView` like below :

```
extension Reactive where Base: NVActivityIndicatorView {

/// Bindable sink for `startAnimating()`, `stopAnimating()` methods.
public var isAnimating: Binder<Bool> {
    return Binder(self.base) { activityIndicator, active in
        if active {
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        } else {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}}
```

And binding data like this:

```
splashVM.loading.bind(to: NVActivityIndicatorView.rx.isAnimating).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

but i get tis error :

```
Instance member 'isAnimating' cannot be used on type 'Reactive<NVActivityIndicatorView>'
```

if I set `isAnimation` static ,that error goes away but another error pops up :

```
Instance member 'base' cannot be used on type 'Reactive<Base>'
```

what's the problem exactly? what should i change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding it wrong. You need to bind to a specific activity indicator view not the class:

```
let activityIndicatorView: NVActivityIndicatorView

splashVM.loading
    .bind(to: activityIndicatorView.rx.isAnimating)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```